# Llenar un Arraylist con números enteros aleatorios entre 1 y 100 y mostrar por pantalla

Tags: java, arraylist, random

Buenas tardes, estoy tratando de hacer un método que genere un arraylist con 40 d
dígitos aleatorios entre 0 y 100 y que devuelva ese array para utilizarlo como entrada de otro método que ordene ese array, ahora mismo tengo generado el arraylist, pero no consigo que me muestre por pantalla las cifras, ¿alguna recomendación?

```
private static CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> aleatorios(){
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> numeros = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    Iterator<Integer> it = numeros.iterator();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Integer vAleatorio;
    for(int i = 0; i<40; i++){
        vAleatorio = (Integer) (rnd.nextInt()*100);
        numeros.add(i,vAleatorio);
    }
    while(it.hasNext()){
        System.out.print(it.next()+" ");
    } 
   return numeros;
}
```

y de cara a ordenar el array, tengo esto

```
public static void ordenarNumeros(CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> numeros){
    int vCambio = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<(numeros.size()-1);i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<numeros.size();j++){
                if(numeros.get(i)>numeros.get(j)){
                    //Intercambiamos valores
                    vCambio=numeros.get(i);
                    numeros.add(i,numeros.get(j));
                    numeros.add(j,vCambio);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Usando Java8 y los stream sería muy sencillo:

```
    int longitud = 40;
    List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>(longitud);

    //Llenar aleatorios
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int i=0;i<longitud;i++){
        lista.add(random.nextInt(100));
    }

    //Imprimir lista
    System.out.println("No ordenados");
    lista.forEach(System.out::println);

    //Ordenar
    lista = lista.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

    //Imprimir lista
    System.out.println("Ordenados");
    lista.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: `Random` tiene un método de instancia, `ints`, que devuelve un `IntStream` de números aleatorios. De esa manera, puedes sacar todavía más partido a los `Stream`: `lista = random.ints(100, 0, 101).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 0):

El metodo `Iterator()` de la clase [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)  retorna una nueva copia de los elementos ya agregados a la lista. Aqui el codigo fuente del metodo [`iterator()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.java#CopyOnWriteArrayList.iterator%28%29):

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
   return new COWIterator<E>(getArray(), 0);
}
```

Por lo que al momento de obtener el `iterator`, este es totalmente independiente de los elementos que agregues después.

Intenta obteniendo el `Iterator` después de agregar los elementos, no antes, para obtener una copia de los elementos que fueron agregados al [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html):

```
private static CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> aleatorios(){
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> numeros = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    Random rnd = new Random();
    Integer vAleatorio;
    for(int i = 0; i<40; i++){
        vAleatorio = (Integer) (rnd.nextInt()*100);
        numeros.add(i,vAleatorio);
    }

    // obtenemos el iterator una vez ya hayamos agregados los elementos a la lista.
    Iterator<Integer> it = numeros.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        System.out.print(it.next()+" ");
    } 
   return numeros;
}
```

Comment: Perfecto! ahora creo que tengo mal algo en la generación de numeros aleatorios, tengo que generar entre 0 y 100 pero me genera numeros desorbitados :)

Comment: Estas utilizando Ramdon para generar los numeros. Porque no utilizas un for para generar numeros del 0 al 100?

Answer (score 0):

¡Ey, que tal amigo!

Acá te envió el código según lo que entendí.

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> numeros = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

        //Recorre para llenar la lista con números aleatorios   
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
            numeros.add((int)(Math.random()*100+1));
            System.out.print(numeros.get(i)+ " ");
        }

        // Esta línea es la que organiza el ArrayList
        Collections.sort(numeros);
        System.out.println();

        for (Integer integer : numeros) 
            System.out.print(integer + " ");
```

Resultado:

```
71 15 83 18 69 75 40 32 29 38 84 65 86 64 67 61 62 12 91 1 9 81 65 46 96 14 3 49 92 95 85 82 82 48 24 61 26 87 31 23 

1 3 9 12 14 15 18 23 24 26 29 31 32 38 40 46 48 49 61 61 62 64 65 65 67 69 71 75 81 82 82 83 84 85 86 87 91 92 95 96
```

¡Espero te sirva, salud2!